# React - Show modal when user clicks on submit, don't hit endpoint until modal button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a standard form in react thats built with react final form. When the user clicks submit, I show a modal to them by updating state to reveal the modal. The modal has two options which update state. I want to wait for one of the options to be clicked before firing the post endpoint.

Here is the form

```
  <div>
    <Wrapper>
      <Form
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
        render={({ handleSubmit }) => (
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate>
            // Fields are here
            <Modal
              isOpen={showModal}
              handleAcceptClick={handleAcceptClick}
              handleDeclineClick={handleDeclineClick}
            />
            <Button
              buttonType="submit"
            />
          </form>
        )}
      />
    </Wrapper>
  </div>
```

// This is the onSubmit methiod

```
  async function onSubmit(submission: Payload) {
    setShowModal(true);
    
    await api.create({
      submission,
    });
  }
```

In the modal component theres a callback to setstate in the same file the form is in, based on if they accept or deny. How can I wait for that state happen before I call the `api.create` method in on submit.

Comment: It's simple: don't call `api.create` inside `onSubmit` but inside `handleAcceptClick`

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div>
    <Wrapper>
        <Form
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
        render={({ handleSubmit }) => (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate>
        // Fields are here
            <Modal
                isOpen={showModal}
                handleAcceptClick={handleAcceptClick}
                handleDeclineClick={handleDeclineClick}
            />
            <Button
                buttonType="button"
                onClick={confirm}
            />
        </form>
        )}
        />
    </Wrapper>
</div>
```

JS CODE:

```
function confirm() {
    setShowModal(true);
}

// call this function on click of one option in modal
function onConfirm(){
    onSubmit();
}
```